# can't concerve react material-ui autoCompletion value with formik

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I hope you're all well, I'm here with this message to express a concern, a problem that I've encountered. I use autoCompletion from materiall-ui combined with formik in reactjs.
I have trouble filling the autoCompletion field in edit mode, I can't display the exact value in my form so I lose the value of my autoCompletion when I switch from one step to another.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use initialValue to set value in Autocomplete, formik + materail ui has data binding issues so you can use https://stackworx.github.io/formik-mui/ sample example here https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-material-ui-autocomplete-rishd?file=/index.js:157-169
PS: Please reload sandbox in case of any dependencies error